# A simple shape derivative example

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $\tau>0$, $U\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open and $T_t$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $U$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$ for $t\in[0,\tau)$ with $T_0=\operatorname{id}_U$. Note that $$V:=\bigcup_{t\in[0,\:\tau)}T_t(U)$$ is open. Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $$\mathcal F(\Omega):=\int_\Omega f\:{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}\;\;\;\text{for }\Omega\in\mathcal B(U)$$ for some $f\in L^1\left(\left.\lambda^{\otimes d}\right|_V\right)$. Now let $$g(t,x):=\left|\det{\rm D}T_t(x)\right|(f\circ T_t)(x)\;\;\;\text{for }(t,x)\in[0,\tau)\times U,$$ $\Omega\in\mathcal B(U)$, $\Omega_t:=T_t(\Omega)\in\mathcal B(V)$ for $t\in[0,\tau)$ and $$G(t):=\int_\Omega g(t,x)\:\lambda^{\otimes d}({\rm d}x)\;\;\;\text{for }t\in[0,\tau).$$ By the substitution rule $$\mathcal F(\Omega_t)=G(t)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau).\tag1$$

> I'd like to find suitable assumptions ensuring that $[0,\tau)\ni t\mapsto\mathcal F(\Omega_t)$ is differentiable at $0$. Moreover, I would like to find further assumptions allowing me write the derivative as an integral over the boundary of $\Omega$.

Ignoring rigor for a moment: Assume there is a $v:[0,\tau)\times V\to\mathbb R^d$ with $$v(t,T_t(x))=\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}(t,x)\;\;\;\text{for all }(t,x)\in(0,\tau)\times U\tag2.$$ Then (still ignoring rigor) $$\left(\frac\partial{\partial t}{\rm D}T\right)(t,x)={\rm D}v(t,T_t(x)){\rm D}T_t(x)\tag3$$ and hence $$\frac\partial{\partial t}(\det{\rm D}T)(t,x)=(\nabla\cdot v)(t,T_t(x))\det{\rm D}T_t(x)\tag4$$ for all $(t,x)\in(0,\tau)\times U$. Now, if $[0,\tau)\times U\ni(t,x)\mapsto{\rm D}T_t(x)$ is continuous in the first argument, then (since $\det{\rm D}T_0=\det\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R^d}=1>0$) there is a $\delta\in(0,\tau]$ such that $\det{\rm D}T_t>0$ for all $t\in[0,\delta)$.

> How can we make these arguments rigorous and include?

*Remark*: I've found the following claim in [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=fjjvX9a9cxUC&pg=PA482&lpg=PA482&dq=%22Basic+Formula+for+Domain+Integrals%22&source=bl&ots=fje9KR4OR2&sig=ACfU3U3Uk0cmdDoP_cMeLeAW4JVYg3TxAg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMwKmQqNfqAhXEyaQKHa8eCPgQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Basic%20Formula%20for%20Domain%20Integrals%22&f=false), but I don't get how they get the differentiability of $t\mapsto J_t$ from their assumptions:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, the cheap answer is that you can just take this as a requirement. Namely you ask $\det DT_t$ to be positive for small $t$. Whether that's useful depends very much on what you are after and whether you can check it in that setting. If your family of diffeos arises as the flow of a $C^1$-vector field, then it is automatically $C^1$ in both $x$ and $t$, so you are continuous after taking a spacial derivative. That would to the job. But what are you after?

Comment: For the second question: Why do you expect a surface integral to pop up anywhere? This might happen if $f$ has a very special form (using Stokes' theorem or the Divergence theorem) and is not in a first instance related with its regularity.

Comment: @JanBohr Please take note of my edit. My concern should be clearer now. Please let me know if anything is sitll unclear.